# How to generate a @CreatedDate LocalDateTime as Timestamp?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using `spring-jpa` to persist a `LocalDateTime created_at` with `@CreatedDate`.

```
@CreatedDate
private LocalDateTime created_at;
```

Problem: this auto-generates a column with `datetime(6)` `mysql` column type.

Question: how can I change this to `TIMESTAMP` type? I tried `@Temporal(TIMESTAMP)` but which is not allowed on `LocalDateTime`.

Is it possible at all?

Comment: According to [https://thoughts-on-java.org/persist-creation-update-timestamps-hibernate/] you can use the Hibernate-specific @CreationTimestamp LocalDateTime from Hibernate 5.2.3 onwards
JPA 2.1 doesn't support LocalDateTime by default.

Answer (score 7):

I could get it working with any of the following solutions:

```
    //spring way, with @EnableJpaAuditing on configuration
    @EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
    class MyEntity {
        @CreatedDate
        @Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP", nullable = false)
        private LocalDateTime created_at;
    }

    //hibernate way
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date created_at;

    //mysql way
    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false,
            columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    private LocalDateTime created_at;
```

For the `mysql` the important part is: `insertable=false` for mysql using the defined `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, and `updatable=false` for `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Otherwise, the hibernate orm would send `created_at=null` as null value to the database, preventing the column definition to take over! Or worse, if you set `nullable=false`, the insert would fail although you defined the default timestamp handling for the column.

Answer (score -3):

You can do one thing Generate the current time according to your required form Using Java there is method called DateTimeFormatter. 
 let me explain through Code:-

---

LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();

DateTimeFormatter dtf1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
String Date = dtf.format(localDate);

and then after assign this Date to your field . It will work Fine.